# Error when getting an object from snapshot java.lang.double to string

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a code to get the snapshot from class but it is showing an error

> java.lang.double to string conversion failed

I am not able to retrive data to create User it is java class and circlememberid is decleared as a string.

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
    for (DataSnapshot dss : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        circlememberid = (dss.child("circlememberid").getValue(String.class));
        usersreference.child((circlememberid)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                createuser =
                        dataSnapshot.getValue(org.electromob.track_it.createuser.class);
                namelist.add(createuser);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test
                        1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do as:

```
String.valueOf(dss.child("circlememberid").getValue());
```